# How to add css class to image tag in Quill Editor

Tags: quill

I want to use Quill with bootstrap.

I need to add `class="img-fluid"` attribute to image tags in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I would try changing the selector on your css first:

```
 .ql-snow .ql-editor img {
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   height: auto;
 }
/*  If your theme is different just change the selector */
```

If that doesn't work I think you can do it by extending the img embed blot, but it might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code that extends the imageBlot, and adds your class to it. It should be fairly easy to adjust if you need something more specific.

```
class ImageBlot extends BlockEmbed {
    static create(value) {
        let node = super.create();
        node.setAttribute('alt', value.alt);
        node.setAttribute('src', value.url);
        node.setAttribute('class', "img-fluid");
        return node;
    }

    static value(node) {
        return {
            alt: node.getAttribute('alt'),
            url: node.getAttribute('src')
        };
    }
}
ImageBlot.blotName = 'image';
ImageBlot.tagName = 'img';

Quill.register(ImageBlot);
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the example. I need to test this, definitely. Can you tell me how this would look like for `li` tags? Because I need to extend the css classes on these elements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I moved on from Quill and haven't touched it for over a year, so I kind of forgot how it all works. Hopefully someone picks up on this and can help you.

Comment: Don't worry. Thank you for your response. Let’s see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to add a custom class on each img tag:

```
var Image = Quill.import('formats/image');
Image.className = 'img-fluid';
Quill.register(Image, true);
```

> https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1728#issuecomment-333064787